# Sum values in a specific hour of the day - Mysql PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datetime

how can I add up the values in a particular hour of day, for example I

```
 id -- name -- value -- date
 1    Example1   31     12-02-2014 12:03:00
 2    Example2   56     13-02-2014 07:40:00
 3    Example3   5      12-02-2014 12:43:00
 4    Example4   31     12-02-2014 11:06:00
```

would like to take for example the values of the day 12-02-2014
at this hour 12

the values that interest me are
Example1
Example3
and the sum: 31 + 5= 36

Comment: Use `SUM()` with a WHERE clause. Make sure your columns are `int`s.

Comment: yes .. but how do I put the hour as a condition

Comment: `WHERE date = '12-02-2014 12:03:00'`

Comment: I need to add up all the values that are at the specified hour, regardless of the minutes

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with jquery. Its better to remove that tag

Comment: Do you want to do this in your MySQL query, using PHP code, or on the front end with JavaScript? Currently the question is unclear on this point and each of the three interpretations will lead to an entirely different answer. Voting to close.

Comment: It's not clear what the datatype of column `date` is, looks sort of a like a datetime, but it's not in standard format... so we are guessing that it's a character type. (If this were a DATETIME datatype, this would be trivial.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using SUM() for the value and in the WHERE clause BETWEEN() for the date

`SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '12-02-2014 12:00:00' AND '12-02-2014 12:59:59'`

If you want to get the results for all hours this is a classic case for a GROUP BY clause:

`SELECT SUM(value), DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:00:00") AS hour FROM table GROUP BY hour`

Comment: This assumes that `date` column is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. This isn't specified in the OP question, and the format of the values in the question makes it appear it might actually be stored as a character datatype.

Comment: @spencer7593 You are right, I assumed that. We just need more information from OP. But if he is using some other datatype, maybe this makes him think about using DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `MYSQL` event and it requires event privilege in the database schema some times it may requires super privilege but this is how you can define an event

you should turn on event scheduler in `MYSQL` client using this statement

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

and then execute this code

```
CREATE EVENT sum
    ON SCHEDULE AT '12-02-2014 12:00:00'
    DO
     UPDATE db.thistable SET val1=SUM(val1,val2);
```

i think this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS total
FROM table
WHERE DATE(date) = '2014-02-12'
AND HOUR(date) = 12
```

N.B.: The date format used will depend on your locale, I've just used it as '2014-02-12' because that works for the 12th of Jan 2014.